# repeat a function inside another function

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am repeating myself badly. I would like to improve my code. You see I am reselecting all the same buttons and action in the second half of my code. How do I reuse the first function inside my `myvideo2.addEventListener("ended")` function?

```
document.querySelector("#AButton").addEventListener("click", function(){                                                                     
  document.querySelector("#videoSphere").setAttribute("src", "video/BlivingRoom1.mp4");       
  if (myvideo2.paused) {
    myvideo2.play();
    console.log("playing BlivingRoom1");
    document.querySelector("#AButton").emit("disappear");                                      
    document.querySelector("#BButton").emit("disappear");
    document.querySelector("#DButton").emit("disappear");
    document.querySelector("#EButton").emit("disappear");
    document.querySelector(".popUpTextIcon1").setAttribute("visible", false);
    document.querySelector("#CButton").emit("move-start");                                
    document.querySelector(".popUpVideoHotspot1").emit("move-start");
  }
  myvideo2.addEventListener("ended", function(){
    document.querySelector("#AButton").emit("disappear");                                      
    document.querySelector("#BButton").emit("disappear");
    document.querySelector("#DButton").emit("disappear");
    document.querySelector("#EButton").emit("disappear");
    document.querySelector("#CButton").emit("move-start");                               
    document.querySelector("#popUpTextIcon1").setAttribute("visible", false);
    document.querySelector(".popUpVideoHotspot1").emit("move-start");
    myvideo2.play();                                                                           
  });
});
```

Comment: Please, please, please, consider this best practice that has been ignored in every answer provided: **Don't call `document.querySelector()` (or any function you don't have to call) on every event**

Comment: Understood!!. But what if I need to querySelect many buttons, and each of them doing different thing. does it mean creating variables is better?

Comment: Yes, creating a variable by running that method just once is better than running the same method over and over and over and (you get it :-). Those DOM nodes are static and getting an reference to them once is all that is necessary. Then just use the reference. I personally would use a DOM Collection through `document.querySelectorAll()` or `document.getElementsByClassName()` - then you could iterate over them as you need to "disappear" them or whatever.

Comment: Please see me answer below...

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract a function and call it in both places.

```
function configurePlayer() {
    document.querySelector("#AButton").emit("disappear");                                      
    document.querySelector("#BButton").emit("disappear");
    document.querySelector("#DButton").emit("disappear");
    document.querySelector("#EButton").emit("disappear");
    document.querySelector(".popUpTextIcon1").setAttribute("visible", false);
    document.querySelector("#CButton").emit("move-start");                                
    document.querySelector(".popUpVideoHotspot1").emit("move-start");
}

document.querySelector("#AButton").addEventListener("click", function(){                                                                     
  document.querySelector("#videoSphere").setAttribute("src", "video/BlivingRoom1.mp4");       
  if (myvideo2.paused) {
    myvideo2.play();
    console.log("playing BlivingRoom1");
    configurePlayer();
  }
  myvideo2.addEventListener("ended", function(){
    configurePlayer();
    myvideo2.play();                                                                           
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is creating an "anonymous function" twice. You could easily create a normal "named" function and call it in your 2 selectors. It would look like:

```js
// a named function **
function dealWithMyButtons() {
    document.querySelector("#AButton").emit("disappear");                                      
    document.querySelector("#BButton").emit("disappear");
    document.querySelector("#DButton").emit("disappear");
    document.querySelector("#EButton").emit("disappear");
    document.querySelector("#CButton").emit("move-start");                               
    document.querySelector("#popUpTextIcon1").setAttribute("visible", false);
    document.querySelector(".popUpVideoHotspot1").emit("move-start");
    if(myvideo2) {
        myvideo2.play();                                                                           
    } else {
        console.log('ERROR: NO myvideo2 to .play()');
    }
}
    
document.querySelector("#AButton").addEventListener("click", function(){                                                                     
    document.querySelector("#videoSphere").setAttribute("src", "video/BlivingRoom1.mp4");       
    if (myvideo2.paused) {
        console.log("playing BlivingRoom1");
        dealWithMyButtons(); // call the function**
    }
    myvideo2.addEventListener("ended", dealWithMyButtons); // listen for event, and call the function** when it occurs
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to change the variables to identifier names that make sense for your application. The code below breaks apart the moving pieces so the code is cleaner and easier to rationalize about. The side effects (changing the DOM) are now isolated to a single function. All the effected DOM elements are clearly identified up front. There is no duplication here and this code is much more performant than repeated calls to `document.querySelector()`.

Food for thought.

The first line of code expects every "disappearable" node to have a custom data attribute named `data-disappearable`. It does not have to have a value.

```
const disapperable = document.querySelectorAll('[data-disappearable]');
const moveStartable = document.querySelector("#CButton");
const clickableButton = document.querySelector("#AButton");
const videoSphere = document.querySelector("#videoSphere");
const popupTextIcon = document.querySelector(".popUpTextIcon1");
const popupVideoHotspot1 = document.querySelector(".popUpVideoHotspot1");

function changePlayState() {
  myvideo2.play();
  disappearable.forEach(el => el.emit("disappear"));
  moveStartable.emit("move-start");
  popupTextIcon.setAttribute("visible", false);
  popupVideoHotspot1.emit("move-start");

}

clickableButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  videoSphere.setAttribute("src", "video/BlivingRoom1.mp4");
  if (myvideo2.paused) {
    changePlayState();
  }
});

myvideo2.addEventListener("ended", function() {
  changePlayState();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like this (in es6):

```
const aButton = document.querySelector("#AButton")
const btns = ["#AButton", "#BButton", "#CButton", "#DButton", "#EButton"]

aButton.addEventListener("click", function(){                                                                     
document.querySelector("#videoSphere").setAttribute("src", "video/BlivingRoom1.mp4");       
if (myvideo2.paused) {
  myvideo2.play();
  console.log("playing BlivingRoom1");
  makeDisappear(btns)
  doStuff()

}
myvideo2.addEventListener("ended", function(){
  makeDisappear(btns)
  doStuff()
  myvideo2.play();                                                                           
});
});

const makeDisappear = (btns) => {
  btns.forEach(btn => document.querySelector(btn).emit("disappear"))
}

const doStuff = () => {
  document.querySelector("#CButton").emit("move-start");  
  document.querySelector(".popUpTextIcon1").setAttribute("visible", false);                              
  document.querySelector(".popUpVideoHotspot1").emit("move-start");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare a function beforehand, like:

```
function myFunction(){
  document.querySelector("#AButton").emit("disappear");                                      
  document.querySelector("#BButton").emit("disappear");
  document.querySelector("#DButton").emit("disappear");
  document.querySelector("#EButton").emit("disappear");
  document.querySelector("#CButton").emit("move-start");                               
  document.querySelector("#popUpTextIcon1").setAttribute("visible", false);
  document.querySelector(".popUpVideoHotspot1").emit("move-start");
}
```

... then in call it in `addEventListener` like:

```
let myElement = document.querySelector("#AButton");
let myEvent = "click"
myElement.addEventListener(myEvent, myFunction);
```

This is actually the main purpose of functions, and anonymous functions are an exception that are sometimes convenient.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing all this in an `AFRAME` custom component, then you can define a custom method

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo' ,{
  init: function() {},
  stuff: function() {}
})
```

and simply call the `stuff` method from `init`:

```
init: function() {
   if (myvideo2.paused) {
     myvideo2.play()
     this.stuff()
   }
   myvideo2.addEventListener("ended", this.stuff)
},
stuff: function() {
   // whatever you need to do
}
```

Like i did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v9ntouyj/1/).